# SQL Server : bitwise or separate fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, bitwise-operators

I am not a DB expert, and not sure what approach would be the best when it comes to query my table.

I have a table `Availability` which contains the days of week a specific user is available to work.

I have defined my model like this

```
     monday: {
      type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: false,
    },
    tuesday: {
      type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: false,
    },
    wednesday: {
      type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: false,
    },
    thursday: {
      type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: false,
    },
    friday: {
      type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: false,
    },
    saturday: {
      type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: false,
    },
    sunday: {
      type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: false,
    },
```

Now, I am wondering, wouldn't it be faster, when it comes to query for all my user available to work e.g. on Monday, to have a single column which contains a bitwise integer so I can insert it by adding all the values and query on it using the `OR` bitwise operator in SQL Server?

Thanks for your help :)

Julien.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking if it is possible or if it is a good approach?

I have done extensive work on a job scheduling tool and my team used the SQL Agent job scheduler in SQL Server as a basis to begin. Under the covers the SQL Agent scheduler is storing the schedule in a table and some of the columns are coded to use bitwise operations against them.

Since there are only 7 days in a week you can use a `tinyint` data type (1 byte = 8 bits) to store this availability data.

```
Ob01000000 could be Monday = 64
0b00100000 could be Tuesday = 32
etc.
```

Then when you pull the data out in a query...

```
WHERE Availability.AvailableDays | 64 = 64
```

will give you anyone who works on Monday.

Personally, I like this approach for these types of problems.

Comment: Hi @thomas, I am just wondering what would be the best practice here. That looks like a good approach indeed. I will give a try. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Internally, SQL Server implements bit columns as a block of bytes in SQL Server.

> The SQL Server Database Engine optimizes storage of bit columns. If
>   there are 8 or less bit columns in a table, the columns are stored as
>   1 byte. If there are from 9 up to 16 bit columns, the columns are
>   stored as 2 bytes, and so on.

[BOL Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql)

I would recommend using `bit` columns.  The database performs all of the bit-wise manipulations for you, so you can write convenient and easy-to-read filter criteria like `where [wednesday] = 1`.

Also, the schema itself prevents an any attempt to set an invalid value in integer columns like `tinyint` and `smallint`.  For example, say you setup a tinyint column that allows 7 bits.  This limits the values from 0 to 127.  A check constraint would be required to prevent someone setting the topmost bit and prevent values between 128 through 255 (inclusive).

Comment: Hi @paul-williams, thanks for your reponse, I indeed think Sequelize would create a BIT by default, that's the current implementation I have. Now I'll lppl how perfs are.